# Binding WPF - escape character "@"

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I've problem with `Binding` to variable which name startswith `@`.

Code:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding @object.name}" Grid.Column="2"></TextBlock>
```

Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: Just try removing the @.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `@` in you binding.

Comment: More to the point: The `@` isn't part of the name, it's just to tell C# it's an identifier that might clash with a keyword. There is no reason at all to carry the `@` over to the Binding syntax because it's not C# there.